# async Do While loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to pull data from an API, but it sends me the data in pages of 100 + the total count of results. The way I tried doing is

```
let count, page = 0;
do {
    ++page
    pullData(page, () => {
        count = data.count
    });
} while (page < count / 100);
```

but the code checks the condition of the loop before count is initialized (page < undefined / 100), and the loop ends up running only the first time.

Is there a way to make the loop wait for the async body to run before checking the condition?

Comment: Well, you can use `await`.

Comment: I tried both `await count = data.count` and `await pullData` with no success

Comment: If `pullData` returns a promise that should work, but if it expects a callback function then you need to "promisify" it first.

Comment: For `await` to work, `pullData` must return a Promise, and `await` keyword must be used inside function with `async` keyword before `function`, like `async function Foo () ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `async/await` or recursive functions like this:

```
const recursive = (page) => {
    pullData(page, () => {
        count = data.count;
        if (page < count / 100) {
            recursive(++page)
        }
    })
}
```